# Can't connect to postgres container from azure pipelines

Tags: postgresql, docker, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to run a postgresql container on an Azure pipelines agent in order to run some unit tests:
Here is my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
resources:
  containers:
    - container: postgres
      image: postgres:13
      env:
        POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: run_unit_tests
    jobs:
      - job: run_unit_tests_1
        services:
          postgres: postgres
        steps:
          - script: |
              sudo apt install -y postgresql-client
              sudo psql --host=postgres --username=postgres --command="SELECT 1;"
```

The error I'm getting is:
`psql: error: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution`

I have mainly followed the suggestions in this issue thread [Problem on connecting to services](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2803),
And the Microsoft docs on [service containers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/using-containerized-services-in-your-pipeline/), which upon getting the same code issue the same resolution error.

Comment: No solutions so far? Maybe it's because Microsoft forbids usage of postgres and wants to promote its own CosmosDB for Postgres that they offer as a service...